# How can I reset a file ignore by git (not configured in .gitignore)?

Tags: git

Looking at ignored files show me:

git status --ignored

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .env

Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    dist/
    src/assets/icon/ui/wind1.svg
```

my .gitignore only contains

```
dist
```

Now I want reset the ignore of src/assets/icon/ui/* files. Where can I change this ignore-configuration?

There is only one .gitignore in my filesystem tree:

```
git ls-files '*.gitignore'
.gitignore
```

Comment: Ignore could be from prior version perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

```
git check-ignore -v src/assets/icon/ui/wind1.svg
/Users/gerd/.config/git/ignore:9:Icon   src/assets/icon/ui/wind1.svg
```

Change /Users/gerd/.config/git/ignore:9

Comment the Icon-exclude pattern.

Details:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore

Answer (score 0):

You can have `.gitignore` files in every subdirectory.

Double check `src`, `src/assets`, `src/assets/icon`, and `src/assets/icon/ui` to make sure you don't have a `.gitignore` file in one of those subfolders also.

You can also run the command `git ls-files '*.gitignore'` inside of your project's directory to list all of the `.gitignore` files.

Comment: There is only one .gitignore file in my tree :(

Comment: Can you check if you have any global ignore files?  Try running "git config --get core.excludesfile"

Comment: Maybe you have a gobal ignore for svg files?